# how to do validations when javascript is disabled in a browser in django

Tags: django, django-models, django-validation

i am using html forms (not using djangoforms). i am managing validations using jquery. But when javascript is disabled i am getting errors in views.py because the values posting from html forms are empty.how can i manage these validations when javascript is disabled. i have tried like this in views.py

```
if time =="" or header=="" or communicationid=="" :
    messages.success(request,'Enter all values')
    return redirect('/samepage/')
```

can i manage them using model validators.if possible please explain

Comment: This is what Django forms are for. You should never rely on JS validation anyway, you always need to validate on the backend.

Comment: is there any other option to handle these errors using html forms?

Comment: Why don't you want to use the Django forms framework? You can still use them in conjunction with your existing HTML. But you can never be certain your data is securely validated until you do it on the backend.

Comment: User input MUST ALWAYS be validated on the server side. Client side validation is more important for user friendly interfaces, not for security.